# Suitable Performance wise Android Background processing method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**Code Summary:**

MainActivity is starting the NearbyPlacesMainActivity using an intent.
In the NearbyPlacesMainActivity, I nested AsyncTask class that gets all the nearby places’ bearings and names and get it stored in an ArrayList and display it.

**My Goal:** My only goal is to pass the nearby places’ names and bearings ArrayList to MainActivity not to update the UI.

**Question:**

As I just want the nearby places’ names and bearings to get stored in ArrayList and then pass it to MainActivity for later use, not to display it right now, so is it a professional approach and suitable performance wise? If not what will be the good approach in this scenario?

*NearbyPlacesMainActivity*

```
package com.example.atifarain.customizedcamera;

public class NearbyPlacesMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
GooglePlaces googlePlaces;
PlacesList nearPlaces;

// KEY Strings
public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference";       // id of the place
public static String KEY_NAME = "name";                 // name of the place

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
ArrayList<String> nearbyData = new ArrayList<String>();
public static double lat1 ;
public static double lon1 ;

MainActivity mainActivityObj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_places_main);

    bearingView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Location location = (Location)extras.get("key1");
    lat1 = location.getLatitude();
    lon1 = location.getLongitude();

    new LoadPlaces().execute();
}

class LoadPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            String types = "cafe|restaurant|atm";
            double radius = 2000;       // 1000 meters
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(lat1, lon1, radius, types);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Get json response status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;

                // Check for all possible status
                if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<Double> bearings = new ArrayList<Double>();

                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);          // Place name

                            double lat2 = p.geometry.location.lat;
                            double lon2 = p.geometry.location.lng;

                            double _bearing = bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
                            bearings.add(_bearing);

                            String lat = Double.toString(lat2);
                            String lon = Double.toString(lon2);
                            String latlon = lat + " , " + lon;

                            coordinates.add(latlon);

                            String nearbyDat = Double.toString(_bearing)+" , "+p.name;
                            nearbyData.add(nearbyDat);

                            placesListItems.add(map);       // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                        }

                        bearingView.setText("");
                        for (int k = 0; k < bearings.size(); k++){
                            bearingView.append(k+1 + ": " + nearbyData.get(k) + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                            "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places", false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR")){
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry unknown error occured.", false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")){
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry query limit to google places is reached", false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED")){
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Request is denied", false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST")){
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request", false);
                }
                else{
                    alert.showAlertDialog(NearbyPlacesMainActivity.this, "Places Error", "Sorry error occured.", false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected double bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double Longitude_Difference = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double latitude_1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double Latitude_2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double y = Math.sin(Longitude_Difference) * Math.cos(Latitude_2);
        double x = Math.cos(latitude_1) * Math.sin(Latitude_2) - Math.sin(latitude_1) * Math.cos(Latitude_2) * Math.cos(Longitude_Difference);
        double result = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
        return (result+360.0d)%360.0d;
    }
}
```

}

*PS. I am very new to android, though I went through all the Handler, Thread and AsyncTask stuff but didn’t get much in practical so I don’t know much about the performance things in android that which are more suitable so please bear with me and if anyone finds it off topic or too broad then before negative voting please do let me know in comments, so I could improve it. Thanks :)*

Comment: `AsyncTask` is fine for this sort of thing, yes.

Comment: This feels like a question that should go in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library which allows you easily communicate between different parts of Android application and prevents from producing related boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I want to point out.

- Creating an AsyncTask as an inner class of your activity could potentially cause a leak since inner classes have an implicit reference to outer one and your background thread may outlive the activity. For example if the screen is rotated while the task is executing, your activity will be destroyed/recreated, you should be handling that case.
- `onPostExecute` already runs on UI thread as per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) so you do not need to explicitly call `runOnUiThread`

There are lot of ways of communicating back to the activity if you move your async task out.  I normally create an interface and have my activity implement that interface.  Then pass the reference to your activity to the AsyncTask but hold on to that reference [Weakly](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) so you don't leak if your activity dies before the AsyncTask completes.  And then invoke the call back from your interface in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Thanks Naveed, I did it by other way but appreciate your reply :)